# Script for Google Docs - automatic calendar - current week and 3 more

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, row

I need your help on a script, please.
I have a calendar in a Google spreadsheet.
I only want to show the current week and 3 more.
So the calendar should "scroll" automatically.

I've already tried adding and deleting lines automatically via macro. But this only works with a fixed amount of lines.
But in my calendar, each week can have a different number of lines.
I have also tried to use a formula to display the current dates, but the text does not move with the dates.

My goal:
Line 1: Headline
Line 2: this current calendar week
Line 3-6: Entries for this week
Line 7: empty
Line 8: next week
and so on

Normally every week has 4 lines for entries, but there can be more than one.
Is there a script for this?
I have never used a script.
I use the Google spreadsheet in German, do I have to pay attention to something special in the script?

Many thanks, greetings Stephan